# Як перекласти російське "не опять, а снова"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

[Російський вислів](https://russian_argo.academic.ru/7484/%D0%9D%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%2C_%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) "Не опять, а снова" вживається як жартівлива відповідь на фразу, яка містить слово "опять".

Цікавить як можна влучно перекласти це слово україньско. Якщо ввести слово "опять" або "снова" в онлайн перекладач (наприклад, Гугл), то він видає один варіант перекладу - "знову". А якщо ввести [повністю фразу](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#view=home&op=translate&sl=ru&tl=uk&text=%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0), то він видає варіант "Не знову, а знову", причому (мені це здається смішним) пише, що цей варіант перевірено і затверджено спільнотою Перекладача... На жаль, більше мені нічого знайти не вдалося.

Можливо в українській мові є якийсь відповідник до такої жартівливої відповіді або ж її можна якось краще перекласти?

Comment: питання не в тому, як перекласти, а чи є відповідник (саме "чи є", бо його не має бути, він лише може бути).

Comment: -1: московською мовою жарт зрозумілий: хтось каже «опять», а інший відповідає цією фразою. А який сенс цього жарту українською мовою? Хтось каже «опʼять», і йому відповідають?

Comment: @bytebuster, така фраза може зустрітися і під час перекладу з російської на українську, і що в такому випадку ви пропонуєте? Упустити її?

Comment: Така фраза може зустрітись в різних контекстах, може в тому. що його описує bytebuster, а може й в тому, що це просто повторення. від цього залежить переклад.

Comment: Можливо, так: "не знову, а заново"?

Answer (score 6):

- Я не до кінця розумію сенс цієї російської відмовки. Але моє розуміння таке… Людина просто каже двічі те саме («не X, а X»), але в другій половині фрази застосовуючи більш рідковживаний, книжковий синонім — просто щоб на секунду спантеличити співрозмовника.

  Повністю ідентичним чином можна побудувати відповідь і в українській мові, застосувавши у другій половині фрази [якийсь більш рідковживаний синонім до *знову*](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/):

  > А: …знову.
  >   Б: Не знову, а наново!

  <sub>Я незгоден з [думкою bytebuster](/q/5649#comment8707_5650) про те, що російське *опять* хтось вважає вульгарним. Можливо ця відмовка спрямована на те, щоб співрозмовник на секунду спантеличено замислився, а чи не вульгарне слово він сказав, але саме слово однозначно не є вульгарним (радше другий синонім є статистично менш уживаним). Але я навіть непевен, що ця фраза обов'язково передбачає саме такий спосіб спантеличення, адже вживаються й інші варіанти, наприклад, [«не снова, а опять»](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D0%B0+%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%22).</sub>
- Можна не застосовувати ту саму формулу (заперечення, за яким навмисне йде самосуперечлива фраза, через що співрозмовник розуміє, що це просто жарт), а навпаки, погодитися й додати [якусь приповідку за значенням «знову»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/), наприклад:

  > А: …знову.
  >   Б: Ага, знов за рибу гроші.

  У такому форматі підходить і [варіант, запропонований P.Vovk](/a/5650), і щось банальніше типу «він/вона/воно/вони [той, кого обговорюють] знов за своє». (Російською ще знаю *[опять двадцать пять](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)*.)

Comment: Дякую, до речі, сьогодні зустрів варіант перекладу "Не наново, а знову!", що близький до того який ви запропонували.

Answer (score 4):

Хочу додати до відповідей приклад того, як українські перекладачі змогли влучно перекласти цей вислів. В мультику "Добриня Микитич та Змій Горинич" вислів "Не опять, а снова" було перекладено:

> -Не знаєш що робити - впав-віджався
>
> -Ще раз?
>
> -Не ще раз, а знову.

Ось [оригінал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvSaBVSAkz4) (діалог на 38:50) та [переклад](http://moviestape.net/katalog_multfilmiv/multfilm/10165-dobrynja-mykytych-ta-zmij-gorynych.html) українською (40:30)

Answer (score 2):

Одразу спадає на думку неймовірно поширений в мережі вислів:

**"Ніколи такого не було, і ось знову!"**

[Ґуґл](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE+%D1%96+%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C+%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%22&ei=pfm0XOqpL-XlrgTzyaSADQ&start=50&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwiqkMeyh9PhAhXlsosKHfMkCdAQ8tMDCG0&biw=1366&bih=657) видає безліч результатів. У вжиток вислів вже увійшов, впізнаваний широкими масами. Вважаю, це найкращий відповідник.

Comment: -1: вислів у запитанні — це обігрування слова «опять», яке деякі московити вважають вульгарним, на відміну від слова «снова». Ваш приклад — це обігрування іншої ситуації, в якій деяка подія виявилася неочікуваною, хоча насправді, вона повторювалася раніше, і варто було очікувати її повторення. Як-то «раптове» настання зими, а водії автівок не змінили покришки на зимові.

Comment: @bytebuster не погоджуюсь. В центрі вислову парадокс того, що щось буде не ще раз, а знову. Тобто, в основі - парадокс. Просто там він на рівні лексики, а тут - на рівні смислу. Щодо вульгарності слова "опять" - дуже дивно, ніколи такого не чув. Думаю, думка про вульгарність цього слова дуже маргінальна, адже я провів у росмовному середовищі оф і онлайн досить багато часу. Сенс виразів однаковий: щось відбувається знову, всі змучились від того, що це відбувається, і жартують з цього приводу. Іноді в укрваріанті набирає додаткових конотацій, але геть не обов'язково.

Comment: Дякую, за такий хороший варіант перекладу!